# iOS: Create default static table in UITableViewCintroller sub-class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to create a default static table in my sub-class of UITableViewCintroller, but data doesn't appear. I don't know where is the problem, I think that cellForRowAtIndexPath method not called.
Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface S5WebTable : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

#import "S5WebTable.h"

@interface S5WebTable ()

@property(assign,nonatomic) BOOL isLoaded;

@end

@implementation S5WebTable

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    [self.tableView sizeToFit];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 7;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    cell.textLabel.text =@":)";

    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Please explain your  problem a bit more.

Comment: I want to use my custom UITableViewController in another UIViewController. And I need, that my controller will be created with default data in tableview.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a distinct identifier for each cell

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%i-r%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //you can customize your cell here because it will be used just for one row.
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to give identifier to tableview cell then it will displays.

e.g.

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_cell", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I to add my  sub-class in another controller class. What I should to do?  I add, something like that:   S5WebTable *tableController = [[S5WebTable alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview: tableController.tableView]; But all cells are empty(

Answer (score 1):

1.Drag TableView Controller in StoryBoard

2.Sele ct the TableView and in Right Inspector change number of `Prototyes Cell(number of cells)` and then  `Dynamic Prototypes` to Static Cell

3.Customise the Cell according to your requirement

Tat's it Static TableView is created.Don't override any of tableview `delegate` or `datasource` methods
Below i added the screenshot of Right Inspector

[image]